# Можно ли добавить в Tkinter изображение с вебкамеры?

Tags: python, tkinter

Имеется окно Tkinter и камера cv2, при запуске кода, сначала открывается окно с камерой, а после его закрытия уже появляется окно Tkinter. Можно ли как-то объединить эти окна так, чтобы изображние с камеры было внутри окна tkinter как картинка, но чтобы при этом изображение двигалось?

```
from tkinter import *
import cv2

screen = Tk()
screen.title("Полноэкранное окно с камерой")
screen.attributes('-fullscreen', 1)
screen['bg'] = '#000000'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
   ret, img = cap.read()
   cv2.imshow("s", img)
   if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:
       break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

посмотри тут. работает.
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/04/21/python-opencv-show-video-tkinter-window/
только учти изображение повернуто, для зеркального отображения добавь
frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
по просьбам полный текст. слямзено - см ссылку.

```
  class App:
   def __init__(self, window, window_title, video_source=0):
       self.window = window
       self.window.title(window_title)
       self.video_source = video_source

       # open video source (by default this will try to open the computer 
          webcam)
       self.vid = MyVideoCapture(self.video_source)

       # Create a canvas that can fit the above video source size
       self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = self.vid.width, height = self.vid.height)
       self.canvas.pack()



       # After it is called once, the update method will be automatically called every delay milliseconds
       self.delay = 15
       self.update()

       self.window.mainloop()

class MyVideoCapture:
   def __init__(self, video_source=0):
       # Open the video source
       self.vid = cv2.VideoCapture(video_source)
       if not self.vid.isOpened():
           raise ValueError("Unable to open video source", video_source)

       # Get video source width and height
       self.width = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
      self.height = self.vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

   def get_frame(self):
       if self.vid.isOpened():
           ret, frame = self.vid.read()
           if ret:
               # Return a boolean success flag and the current frame converted to BGR
               return (ret, cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
           else:
               return (ret, None)
       else:
           return (ret, None)
```

в общем так-
делаем окно, в нем объект типа Canvas
с камеры через cv2 захватываем видео и в объект помещаем как картинку. обновляем.
повторить пока не надоест )))
вызов a = APP(tkinter.tk(), 'имя окна')
может чего и не до конца перенес - см ссылку - я сам по этому примеру разбирался.

Comment: Я вызываю через код `a = (tkinter.Tk(),'имя окна')`, а как мне завершить его?